# How do I open a Word document in a web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, word, page-viewer-web-part

I want to display a .docx (Word) document in a Sharepoint page.
I have a sharepoint page with a Page Viewer web part an a Word document on the same Sharepoint site. What I'm trying to do is the following :

- Copy the link to the word document
- Open the tool pane for the web part
- Copy the link to the word document in the link text box
- Click ok

The document is not displayed, and when I re-open the tool pane, the link has disappeared. See screenshots below :
[image: Empty page viewer after adding link]

[image: Link text box goes back to default]

I assume I'm doing something wrong, but I get 0 feedback from Sharepoint. No error, the link (when I test it) works, etc...

Comment: which sharepoint you are using...online?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Yes, Sharepoint Online.

Comment: Check notes from my answer and make sure you have done both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to achieve this:

1. Go to your SharePoint page.
2. Add web part from : Media and Content > Page Viewer Web Part > Insert
3. Edit web part properties.
4. Keep web part settings as "Web Page"(first option in web part properties).
5. Copy the link of a document file in a document library from the ellipsis(...) with `?Web=1`.
6. Paste URL in the Link field of web part.
7. Click Apply.
8. Resize web part height from "Appearance" if needed.
9. Save page.

**Note**:

1. The URL to the Word/PDF file will end with the parameter `?Web=1` after the file name as this is what makes a office document open in Office Web Apps. So keep it as it is.
2. If the office Web Apps installed and connected to your SharePoint farm then it will render the document file on the web page inside Word Web App.

**Update**:

1. For Modern Pages on SharePoint online, you can use the file viewer web part on pages.
2. Use the File viewer web part to insert a file on your page. File types you can insert include Excel, Word, PowerPoint, Visio, PDFs, 3D models, and more.

   **Source**:

   1. [Use the File viewer web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-file-viewer-web-part-e53a9602-e7b3-4fff-9126-de2f18d1900c).

Comment: This is exactly what I did, minus the ``?Web=1`` thing. I tried that just now and it makes no difference. Also, clicking ``apply`` instead of ``ok`` doesn't change anything.

Comment: do you have office web apps installed and connected on sharepoint/

Comment: After adding URL of document in Link field, Test the Link using option given in web part properties. it is working or not?

Comment: The weird thing is, one of my colleagues managed to get a document displayed. So I'm assuming that yes, the office web apps are installed. Also I can open the document in Word online without an issue by just clicking on it, or by clicking the ``test link`` thing in the control pane for the Web Part.

Comment: Strange. are you getting any error in browser console? or try deleting and re-adding the web part.

Comment: Yeah, we figured it out. It had to do with some 'security' measure. Thanks for the help !

Comment: What was the exact issue of security?

Comment: Permissions. Not at all obvious from the absence of feedback given by SharePoint.
Also, I had a lot of errors in the console, but they were caused by some other software.
Also, another very weird thing, in Chrome, I ended up not even having the permission to see the page after my colleague had modified the page, while I could see it in IE.