# How do I dispaly contents of word document in sharepoint 2013 enterprise edition

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How do I dispaly contents of word document in sharepoint 2013 enterprise edition. I need to display contents of word document on SharePoint.
I don't want open in WORD.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to achieve this:

1. Go to your SharePoint page.
2. Add web part from : Media and Content > Page Viewer Web Part > Insert
3. Edit web part properties.
4. Keep web part settings as "Web Page"(first option in web part properties).
5. Copy the link of a document file in a document library from the ellipsis(...) with `?Web=1`.
6. Paste URL in the Link field of web part.
7. Click Apply.
8. Resize web part height from "Appearance" if needed.
9. Save page.

**Note**:

1. The url to the word/pdf file will end with the parameter `?Web=1` after the file name as this is what makes a office document open in Office Web Apps. So keep it as it is.
2. If the office Web Apps installed and connected to your SharePoint farm then it will render the document file on the web page inside Word Web App.

**Source**:
1. [How do I open a Word document in a web part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/253233/how-do-i-open-a-word-document-in-a-web-part/253237).