# Is it possible to cross reference figures/images on a sharepoint page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, word

I have a bunch of text figures that point to scattered images, and I would like to be able to cross reference them like Word can. However I can't seem to find any native functionality for this - are there other viable options?

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you trying to create hyperlinks? What are text figures?

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to do a sort of in-text citation - i.e. Figure 29 refers to the dog. Picture of a dog has a caption Figure 29. I'd like to be able to just jump to the caption

Answer (score 0):

In Out of the box SharePoint, it is not possible. However you can try using one of the below approache:

1. **Promoted Links**: You can use promoted links list. In this list you can add images and caption/description to image very easily. It will show image and its caption in fancy way.
2. **Word document with Page viewer**: You can add the images in your word document(which you already knows) and store this document in one of the document library on site. And show this document in page viewer web part.

**Reference**: [How do I open a Word document in a web part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/253233/how-do-i-open-a-word-document-in-a-web-part/253237)